# IOMMU with nvme hardrive leads to occaasional system crash - nvme unable to read/write

Tags: linux, debian, qemu

I'm suffering from random crashes of my system - i7-7700K, GA-Z270X-UD3, and Debian/testing.

The crash does not save any output to /var/log, which sounds logic, because on the screen I see some debug info about the system being unable to write anything to /dev/nvme partitions, moreover I can't even properly unmount nor reboot the system - the disk behaves as if it is unplugged.

I've been trying to diagnose the problem for over 6 months, and I've finally found something - IOMMU. After a clean reinstallation not a single crash for over a month - until I've enabled iommu, because I wanted to passthrough a GPU (old Nvidia Quadro) to a virtual machine.

I suffered from the crushes even when that GPU was unplugged, so it's not that GPU.

I'm quite sure that's somehow related to the IOMMU - those crashes appeared even without any virtual machine running, without any device passthrough. After a clean reinstallation before re-enabling IOMMU - not a single one.

Have anybody came across  a similar issue? What I could do? Report a bug, without any useful debug info?

Virtual machines and GPU passthrough run really good without any issues, the crash seems to correlate with the computer being used (it has been running stable for a week or two if left @idle). It's otherwise random. I'm using qemu-kvm.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. It was (probably) just a faulty Power Supply Unit, which gave symptoms only under heavy load, like multiple OSes to handle.